# Getting user Facebbok id from last Sharekit version?

Tags: facebook, sharekit

I updated to Sharekit last version since few days and it's all ok for sharing, however I need in some app to get user Facebook ID. I explain what I'm doing : when the user launch first the app, I check the NSUserDefaults as below :

```
 NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSLog(@"user : %@",[userPreferences valueForKey:@"userId"]);
```

to see if he is already registred in my database. In the other case, I show a view to let him connect with Facebook like this :

```
 [SHKFacebook   getUserInfo];

 NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(registerFacebook)
               name:@"SHKSendDidFinish"
             object:nil];
```

and here is the method

```
- (void)registerFacebook {


NSDictionary *facebookUserInfo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kSHKFacebookUserInfo"];

fbid= [facebookUserInfo objectForKey:@"id"];

NSLog(@"registred = %@",fbid);


NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userPreferences setValue:fbid forKey:@"userId"] ;

.... }
```

It works well with IOS 6 and 6.1, but with IOS5 it seems not getting the user id, even I'm using forcePreIOS6FacebookPosting to YES.

Any idea?